# Troubleshoot Chrome Search Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying to make a basic chrome extension that will search the Wayback Machine based off a link. I'm trying to set it up so that when I right-click a link, the context menu has a 'go to wayback machine' option. This is what I have:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name" : "Archive Right Click",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "version" : "1.0",
  "description" : "Adds Go to Archive to right-click context menu.",
  "icons" : {
    "16" : "icon-16.png",
    "48" : "icon-48.png"
  },
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_icon": "icon-16.png",
    "default_title" : "Go to Archive"
  },
  "permissions" : [
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["script.js"]
  }
}
```

script.js:

```
function searchArchive(info,tab) {
    var url = info.linkUrl;
    var archiveURL = "https://web.archive.org/web/*/" + url;
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url : archiveURL,
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {
        "context" : ["link"],
        "title" : "Open link in Archive",
        "onclick" : searchArchive
    });
```

The problem is that it doesn't even show up in the context menu let alone open the tab I want.

Let me know about any useful tutorials on chrome extensions. I haven't been able to find a beginner resource that provides good examples.

Comment: Voted to close as typographical error.

Comment: P.S. you don't need `tabs` permission to use `tabs.create`. It generates scary warnings (for a reason) so you are better off without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `context` by `contexts` in your script.js

```
function searchArchive(info,tab) {
    var url = info.linkUrl;
    var archiveURL = "https://web.archive.org/web/*/" + url;
    chrome.tabs.create({
        url : archiveURL,
    });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "contexts" : ["link"]
    "title" : "Open link in Archive",
    "onclick" : searchArchive
});
```

Comment: If you are happy with the response, I appreciate if you can mark as correct (green tick) Thanks!!!

Comment: Checked! I'm still new to stackoverflow.